# Repeat two different animations infinitely in android one after the other

Tags: android, animation

I am trying the following code in Andorid for animations

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lay);
        rel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
        rel.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_background));


        animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(3);
        rel.startAnimation(animation);

        animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        animation1.setDuration(1500);
        animation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation1.setRepeatCount(3);

        animationchala();




    }

   public void  animationchala(){
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                animation.setAnimationListener(null);

                rel.startAnimation(animation1);


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation1) {

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation1) {
                animation1.setAnimationListener(null);
                rel.startAnimation(animation);


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation1) {
            }
        });
    }
```

the code works for the first time.

when animation ends animation1 is started , then animation1 ends and animation is started again, but now when animation1 has to start again it stops, how can I repeat the animations one after the other infinitely

Comment: Did you try to use a infinite loop e.g. while(true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your case that you are setting your `animationListeners` to `null` when you started new animation. This makes them stop after you started animation. Just re-arrange your codes like this;

```
public void  animationchala(){
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rel.startAnimation(animation1);


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation1) {

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation1) {
            rel.startAnimation(animation);


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation1) {
        }
    });
}
```